# e or tabe into path resulting from a ! command

Tags: external-command, tabbed-user-interface

Given a bash function, `getMyFilePath()`, which results in a directory path, `/mydir`, how can I open a new tab, passing this function to navigate there?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `execute` and `system`:

```
execute "tabnew ".system("getMyFilePath()")
```

But most likely you could solve your use case without the function.
Have a look at [:h filename-modifiers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers)